# how to minimize function for equal value

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize  afunction in matlab like this:

```
function [c, ceq] = const_slot( x )
c = [];
% Nonlinear equality constraints
ceq = [sum(x)-1];
end



[x,fval] = fmincon(@func_slot, x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@const_slot,options)
```

But, I need to value `fval` that was within the specified value, or the positive. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear: `fval` is an output. Do you mean you have trouble finding `x0` - the initial point for the optimization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question you want to put constraints on your function `@func_slot` (which I assume is non-linear).

In the [Matlab help for fmincon](http://www.mathworks.se/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) we find:

```
x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options)
```

Non-linear constraints can be set using the `nonlcon` parameter (in the question you use `@const_slot`). These constraints should be defined as:

```
function [c,ceq] = mycon(x)
c = ...     % # Compute nonlinear inequalities at x.
ceq = ...   % # Compute nonlinear equalities at x.
```

So for example, when you want your function `@func_slot` to be greater than zero, you can define the inequality constraint `c` in `@const_slot` as the negative of your function.

**Edit**

If I understand you correctly, you need the function value to be greater than zero but less than a specified limit. In that case you could try this.

```
function [c, ceq] = const_slot( x )

% # Nonlinear inequality constraints
upperLimit = 10;
c = [-func_slot(x);
     -upperLimit + func_slot(x)];

% # Nonlinear equality constraints
ceq = [sum(x)-1];

end
```

Comment: I already use constraints for x value. function [c, ceq] = const_slot( x )
c = [];
ceq = [sum(x)-1];
end  I need hold value fval in zero or the specified value, value of the function and not a variable x.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, it would seems like you are trying to find all zeros of `func_slot` lying in the domain `lb <= x <= ub` and `sum(x) = 1`. 
 
1. If this is the case, please re-phrase your question to reflect this - you'll get better answers. 
 
2. The constraint `sum(x)=1` is a **linear** constraint, you can use `Aeq = ones(1, size(x,1))` and `beq = 1` to achieve the same thing. Doing so, you can now use `const_slot` to reflect your nonlinear requirement

```
function [c, ceq] = const_slot( x )
c = [];
ceq = func_slot(x) - desired_fval;
```